# How to only generate the chrome.sln when trying to compile the chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am trying to compile the chromium.

I have downloaded the source code using git clone from googlesource.(Due to network problems, it's impossible for me to get code form chroumium.org)

I have tried to use "gclient runhooks --force" and this command started to download windows sdk and visual studio. I have already installed the windows sdk manually and visual studio 2013 professional with update 4 so there's no need to do so.

Please tell me how to generate the chrome.sln only without downloading visual studio and windows sdk?

Comment: Try asking on the `chromium-dev` mailing list. I don't think that you're going to get an answer to this specific question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. And by the way, does the mailing list mean the discussion group at http://www.chromium.org/developers/discussion-groups ?

Comment: Yes. After joining the group using a Google account, you can use that account to send mails to chromium-dev at chromium dot org (or use the web interface to post to the mailing list).